# Changing the decay rate of a radioisotope by bombarding it with radiation

Tags: nuclear-physics

I was wondering if we could "artificially" increase the decay rate of a radioisotope by bombarding it with radiation. I've taken a look at other answers, but they do not clearly state if it is possible or not.

**What is the general consensus on if we can increase the decay rate of a rate of a radioisotope by means of radiation bombardment?**

edit: I'm looking at specifically increasing the rate of decay for a beta decay isotope. Some methods I have heard of are gamma ray bombardment and neutron bombardment.

Comment: For neutrino flux, the answer [appears to be no](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5071).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beta decay is in fact mutable. Ray Davis published a few papers well worth reading. But if you ionize an unstable nuclei, the beta particle, which is basically an electron, has new lower energy states it can occupy, which by Fermi's golden rule means the beta decay rate will increase.

If a neutrino is its own anti-particle, then in the Feynman diagram allows you to move the anti-neutrino from the decay side to the other side by changing it to a neutrino, which is allowed. Given the likely tiny cross section, the decay rate would have a component based on the neutrino flux.

You can change the decay rate with photons as well, Griffith's undergraduate text book has a section in the back on Zeno effect. A photon interacting in the nucleus will collapse the wave function and restart the clock for decay. There are lots of details to this, but it works.